# How can I run programs in tmux panes simultaneously?

Tags: linux, python, tmux

I'm trying to make a script that opens up 4 tmux panes, and launch a python program inside of it. I want to do it simultaneously, but I don't know how.

I tried

```
tmux new-session "python 'DogeClickBot (2)'/main.py $1 ; read\" && tmux split-window \"python LTCClickBot/main.py $1 ; read"
```

The first Python program launches, but not the second. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The escaped double-quotes make `tmux` run the following in a new session:

```
python 'DogeClickBot (2)'/main.py substituted1 ; read" && tmux split-window "python LTCClickBot/main.py substituted1 ; read
```

and because of quoting `read && tmux split-window python` is interpreted as a *single* command name, as if you invoked

```
python … ; "read && tmux split-window python" …
```

This makes no sense.

---

Unescaped double-quotes make more sense:

```
tmux new-session -d "python 'DogeClickBot (2)'/main.py $1 ; read" && tmux split-window "python LTCClickBot/main.py $1 ; read"
```

This way in the current shell you run `tmux new-session … && tmux split-window …`, which is probably what you wanted.

Note I added `-d` because without it the first command would attach to the session and the next part (`&& …`) would not be executed until you detached or the session was destroyed. The right thing is to attach at the very end (`tmux attach`).

Be aware this straightforward approach may introduce a race condition: what if the session dies before `tmux split-window` runs? More about it in [this another answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1492284/432690). The most relevant fragment:

> `tmux new-window …` [`tmux new-session …` in your case] is a command for the tmux server, `tmux` here is just a client. After the client exits successfully, you can be sure a new window [session] has been created; but you cannot really know what happens in it, on what stage, or if the window [session] has not been already destroyed.

---

Additionally ask yourself if you don't want to quote whatever `$1` expands to. In this fragment:

```
tmux new-session "python 'DogeClickBot (2)'/main.py $1 ; read"
```

the parameter is properly double-quoted. Then the shell spawned by the tmux server will run this:

```
python 'DogeClickBot (2)'/main.py substituted1 ; read
```

where `substituted1` is what `$1` expanded to. Leaving it unquoted at this stage can have [similar consequences](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) as leaving `$1` unquoted. Maybe this is what you want, maybe not. If not, then most likely you need:

```
tmux new-session "python 'DogeClickBot (2)'/main.py '$1' ; read"
```

and similar additional quoting in the second command.

Comment: Well, nothing happens. There's no error message.

Comment: @KrystStalin Did you attach? Note I used `new-session -d`.

Comment: I tried with `tmux new-session -d "python 'DogeClickBot (2)'/main.py $1 ; read" && tmux split-window "python LTCClickBot/main.py $1 ; read"`

Comment: @KrystStalin So you didn't. Attach then: `tmux a`

Comment: @KrystStalin You're using `split-window` without specifying the target (`-t`). This may be the culprit if the newly created session is not the only session. Please see `man 1 tmux` and learn how tmux chooses targets implicitly. Name the session and the window (`new-session -s foo -n bar`) and then target them explicitly `split-window -t foo:bar`. Is it better?

Comment: It works. Thanks.