# How to create a tmux session with two windows with specific name and run specific scripts in each window?

Tags: shell, tmux

I want to create a session with the name - `general`
And I want to have two windows in it -

1. win1
2. win2

And I need to run script1 in win1
and script2 in win2

Currently I have written the script like -

```
SESSION="general"
echo $SESSION
tmux attach-session -d -t $SESSION || tmux new-session -s $SESSION -n win1 -c  /my/path/ ./script1.sh
tmux new-window -n win2 tel_csr
```

With this script, I am able to create a session with the name `general`. But only one window is coming up with the name `win1` and running the script - `script1.sh`.

The second statement is not kicking in. What is wrong with the above script.

Note: `script1.sh` triggers a server program, so it doesn't return I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Analysis

> What is wrong with the above script?

Run `sleep 5; echo done`. Are you surprised `echo` works only after `sleep` exits? The shell runs the two commands in sequence, not in parallel.

Now run `less /etc/fstab; echo done`. You will see `done` only after you exit from `less` (with <kbd>Q</kbd>).

`tmux new-session; tmux new-window` is no different.

In your script `tmux attach-session` or `tmux new-session` *attaches* to a session. One or the other `tmux` command becomes a tmux client and it runs until you detach. The script waits for this `tmux` to exit before executing the next command. You cannot see the effect of `tmux new-window` before you detach because this command has not been executed yet.

If you detach then you will allow the script to continue. Do it without destroying the session, attach again and you will see the new window.

---

#### Solution

Attach after you set everything up.

Set everything up using commands that don't attach to the session (e.g. `tmux new-session -d`). If you eventually want to attach then `tmux attach-session` should be the *last* command in the script (unless you *deliberately* want to do something extra after you detach). This example (run it outside of tmux) will attach to a session where an additional window already exists:

```sh
tmux new-session -d
tmux new-window
tmux attach-session
```

In general you want to name and target the exact session, window etc. And you want some logic to handle a situation when the named session exists etc.

---

#### Alternative

An alternative approach is to invoke some "maintenance" commands from a subshell running asynchronously and attach early from the main shell, with the "maintenance" part still running in parallel. Example (run it outside of tmux):

```sh
(tmux new-session -d; sleep 5; tmux new-window) & sleep 2; tmux attach-session
```

`sleep 5` simulates commands that take time. With the previous solution you would have to wait until all of them finish. Here you don't have to wait that long, you attach before `tmux new-window` runs. This way you can actually see a new window popping out in tmux.

This method has serious disadvantages though:

- You can interact with tmux even before everything is set up. By changing the current pane (or window etc.) or destroying some pane (or window etc.) you can cause the "maintenance" commands to target the wrong pane (or window etc.) or to fail; unless they are carefully crafted to handle such situation.
- Race conditions. In the above example `sleep 2` delays `attach-session` so it hopefully runs after `new-session`. Even with `sleep 2` (or even with `sleep 2000`) there is no guarantee `new-session` runs first, only high probability. There is `tmux wait-for` to handle such situations (but using it right can be tricky; see "Dealing with race conditions" in [this another answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1492284/432690)).

Comment: Okay, understood the concept. I'll try this and update. Thanks

Comment: The solution you have proposed is working well unless i specify a shell-command to run inside each window.

Comment: It is working now. In the first tmux command I was using -d option at the end. Ie after the shell-command. That was the problem. And in the second tmux command, I was using the bash alias as shell-command. Expanded that alias. Now it is working.

Comment: How can I make the alias work? I have included #!/bin/bash as the first line of the script as well

Comment: @DarshanL It's definitely a separate issue. Please ask a separate question (after searching and  researching; maybe a similar question already exists).